# Chirping a sinusoid

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, complex-numbers

Below is my code
where I am wanting to sweep a 400MHz tone between -50Mhz and 50Mhz. Meaning the
sweep should span between 350MHz and 450MHz. But that is no the case. Don't
understand what the reason for this is. It has been suggested that this is because frequency is the derivative of the phase. I have given that a shot too in the commented lines in the 'sweep_sine' function but that does not seem to help either. Any help would be appreciated.

Image of unexpected program output added. As you can see I am able to shift my 400MHz tone to 300MHz. When I try to sweep in a fashion similar to shift; the output is incorrect, as in it does not sweep from 350MHz to 450MHz with the 400MHz tone in the middle.

I am able to sweep the signal correctly now as can be seen in image 2. The time domain signal also looks fine when the signal is of the e^i2*pi*f*t form. But when I use a real signal of the form sin(2*pi*f*t) the time domain version looks corrupted (image 3). What could be the reason for that? Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H1Dk.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey3tQ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzmDS.png

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gen_sig(freq=380e6, fs=6080e6, n_samp=6400):
    ts = 1/fs
    t_arr = np.arange(0, n_samp)*ts
    sig = np.exp(2 * 1j * np.pi * freq * t_arr)
    #sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t_arr)
    return sig,ts

def freq_shift_sine(sine, ts, shift_freq = 50e6):
    tx_sig_t = np.linspace(0, ts*sine.shape[-1], num=sine.shape[-1])
    #tx_sig_sqrd =  np.square(tx_sig_t)
    #hift the sine
    freq_shftd_sig = sine * np.exp(1.0j * 2 * np.pi * (shift_freq * tx_sig_t))
    #freq_shftd_sig = sine * np.exp(1.0j * np.pi * (shift_freq * tx_sig_sqrd))    
    return freq_shftd_sig

def sweep_sine(sine, ts, up_lim = 50e6, low_lim = -50e6):
    tx_sig_t = np.arange(0, sine.shape[-1])*ts
    tx_sig_sqrd =  np.square(tx_sig_t)
    phi = low_lim*tx_sig_t + (up_lim-low_lim)*(tx_sig_sqrd/(2*ts*sine.shape[-1]))
    dopp_shftd_sig = sine * np.exp(1.0j* 2 *np.pi * phi)
    return dopp_shftd_sig   

if __name__=='__main__':
    #generate a sine wave 16 times over sampled
    tx_sig, t_samp = gen_sig(freq=400e6, fs=6400e6, n_samp=6400)
    #do an fft
    tx_sig_fft = np.fft.fft(tx_sig)
    #generate freqency axis for fft
    freq_arr = np.fft.fftfreq(tx_sig.shape[-1], t_samp)
    #shift sine wave
    tx_sig_shifted = freq_shift_sine(tx_sig, t_samp, shift_freq = -100e6)
    #fft the shifted sine
    tx_sig_shftd_fft = np.fft.fft(tx_sig_shifted) 
    #sweep sine wave by up_lim+low_lim Hz
    tx_sig_swept = sweep_sine(tx_sig, t_samp, up_lim = 50e6, low_lim = -50e6)
    #fft the swept sine
    tx_sig_swept_fft = np.fft.fft(tx_sig_swept)    
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(freq_arr, abs(tx_sig_fft))
    plt.plot(freq_arr, abs(tx_sig_shftd_fft))       
    plt.plot(freq_arr, abs(tx_sig_swept_fft))
    plt.axis([0,1e9, 0, 2e3])
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(tx_sig)
    plt.plot(tx_sig_shifted)
    plt.plot(tx_sig_swept)    
    plt.axis([0,100, -1.2, 1.2])
```

Comment: It wasn't clear to me what do you try to achieve. only from the name `dopp` I finally realized that you want a transformation for a tone. The transformation should mimic Doppler's effect. Is it right?

Comment: I would have a loop where I am synthesizing the curve however to achieve the gradual frequency shift I would alter the size of delta I apply to the theta which is what I am feeding into the sin function

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity, to put it simply what complex exponential do  I multiply    sine_sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t_arr) to sweep the sine_sig from freq - sweep_start to freq + sweep_finish

Comment: @rth that is correct. In the image now in the original post I am able to see a sweep but with incorrect starting and ending frequencies to the ones I provided in the main function of the program.

Comment: @zoulzubazz Please try to plot the signals vs time. You can find that after both of your functions: constant shift and Doppler's transformation, signals don't look like a sin wave.

Comment: @rth. I am sorry, but the shifted one does look like a sinusoid. The doppler transformation one does not because there is something wrong in the math I am applying, which is precisely what I would like to understand.

Comment: That is really strange, please update the code which you use to plot 'signals' and graphs which you have got.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I think the problem is in your signal. You have only a real part of it, and shifting the phase in the complex plane doesn't help so much in the real part.

The possible treatment for this problem is to make the signal a complex one. The best way is to make a Hilbert transform and use it as a signal.

Your code may look like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import hilbert


def gen_sine(freq=380e6, fs=6080e6, n_samp=6400):
    ts = 1/fs
    t_arr = np.arange(0, n_samp)*ts
    #sine_sig = np.exp(2 * 1j * np.pi * freq * t_arr)
    sine_sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t_arr)
    return sine_sig,ts

def freq_shift_sine(sine, ts, shift_freq = 50e6):
    tx_sig_t = np.linspace(0, ts*sine.shape[-1], num=sine.shape[-1])
    #tx_sig_sqrd =  np.square(tx_sig_t)
    #hift the sine
    freq_shftd_sig = hilbert(tx_sig) * np.exp(1.0j * 2 * np.pi * (shift_freq * tx_sig_t))
    #freq_shftd_sig = sine * np.exp(1.0j * np.pi * (shift_freq * tx_sig_sqrd))    
    return freq_shftd_sig

def sweep_sine(sine, ts, up_lim = 50e6, low_lim = -50e6):
    #tx_sig_t = np.arange(0, sine.shape[-1])*ts 
    tx_sig_t = np.linspace(0, ts*sine.shape[-1], num=sine.shape[-1])
    #tx_sig_sqrd =  np.square(tx_sig_t)   
    freq_step_arr = np.linspace(low_lim, up_lim, sine.shape[-1])
    dopp_shftd_sig = hilbert(tx_sig) * np.exp(1.0j * 2 * np.pi * (freq_step_arr * tx_sig_t))
    #dopp_shftd_sig = sine * np.exp(1.0j * np.pi * (freq_step_arr * tx_sig_sqrd))
    return dopp_shftd_sig

if __name__=='__main__':
    #generate a sine wave 16 times over sampled
    tx_sig, t_samp = gen_sine(freq=400e6, fs=6400e6, n_samp=6400)
    #do an fft
    tx_sig_fft = np.fft.fft(tx_sig)
    #generate freqency axis for fft
    freq_arr = np.fft.fftfreq(tx_sig.shape[-1], t_samp)
    #shift sine wave
    tx_sig_shifted = freq_shift_sine(tx_sig, t_samp, shift_freq = -100e6)
    #fft the shifted sine
    tx_sig_shftd_fft = np.fft.fft(tx_sig_shifted) 
    #sweep sine wave by up_lim+low_lim Hz
    tx_sig_swept = sweep_sine(tx_sig, t_samp, up_lim = 50e6, low_lim = -50e6)
     #fft the swept sine
    tx_sig_swept_fft = np.fft.fft(tx_sig_swept)    
    #plt.figure()
    #plt.plot(freq_arr, abs(tx_sig_swept_fft))    
    #plot sine wave fft
    #plt.figure()
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(freq_arr, abs(tx_sig_fft))
    plt.plot(freq_arr, abs(tx_sig_shftd_fft))       
    plt.plot(freq_arr, abs(tx_sig_swept_fft))
    plt.axis([0,1e9, 0, 2e3])
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.specgram(tx_sig_swept, NFFT=80, Fs=6400e6, noverlap=16)
    #plt.axis([0,0.000001, 0, 5e6])
    plt.figure(3)
    plt.subplot(311)
    t_time = np.arange(0, tx_sig.shape[-1])*t_samp
    plt.plot(t_time, tx_sig)
    plt.plot(t_time, np.imag(hilbert(tx_sig)) )
    plt.subplot(312)
    plt.plot(t_time, tx_sig_shifted)
    plt.subplot(313)
    plt.plot(t_time, tx_sig_swept )
    plt.show()
```

It produces more or less ok spectrogram and doesn't corrupt the resulted signal. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a very common mistake.  Incrementing both the frequency and the time (when you multiply them to create a phase parameter input for the exp or sine function) at each time step, increments the frequency too much.  Instead figure out how much the phase should change at each new time step for the desired frequency at that time step, and **add** that phase delta instead of doing a multiplication to get a new phase input to your sine or exp function.

Comment: What if the signal isn't a tone (sin wave)? Would the additional phase work?

Comment: If the signal is periodic and can be indexed or parameterized by phase